# Problem getting latest from TFS 2010 server with TFS 2008 build with UpgradeTemplate

Tags: tfs

With a Controller and Agent running on a machine with a TFS 2010 Build Service (updated from TFS 2008), I run a TFS 2008 build using the UpgradeTemplate. The TFS 2010 Server where the latest code resides is not the same machine as my target build machine in this scenario. However, an AfterGet task fails straight away because the Get never actually happens. I examined the BuildLog and found the following:

```
Using "Get" task from assembly "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Team Foundation Server
2010\Tools\\Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.ProcessComponents.dll".
Task "Get" (TaskId:14)
  Get TeamFoundationServerUrl="<tfs server link>/tfs/<project collection>" 
  BuildUri="vstfs:///Build/Build/4436" AllowUnmapped=True AutoMerge=True 
  BuildDirectory="<build directory>" Force=True NoCIOption=True Overwrite=False 
  PopulateOutput=False Preview=False Recursive=True Version="C17274" 
  Workspace="<workspace name>" (TaskId:14)
Done executing task "Get". (TaskId:14)
```

As you can see, the Get finishes without actually downloading any source. I figure that it is either: 1) something wrong with the server, 2) upgrading to TFS 2010 Build service from TFS 2008 broke something, or 3) the Get task is faulty when using the UpgradeTemplate.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Did you take a look at the workspace mappings in the build definition?

Comment: The Source Control Folder is pointing to the root folder of my solution, and the Build Agent Folder has the value $(SourceDir). Thanks for taking a look!

Comment: Also, when I tried running a build using the Default Template, the Get operation worked fine.